# How to add values as list to key

Tags: python

I have list of dictionary `[{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'1', 'eid':'3'},{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'2'},  {'name':'ABC', 'jid':'2'},{'name':'CDE', 'jid':'1'}]`

How to add same values to list also unique values has to take

Expected out

`[{'name':'ABC', 'jid':['1','2']}, {'name':'CDE', 'jid':'1'}]`

Comment: That is not a dictionary rather a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the list of dictionaries:

```
jdict = {}

dlist = [{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'1', 'eid': 1},{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'2'}, {'name':'CDE', 'jid':'1'}]
for ddict in dlist:
  if ddict['name'] not in jdict:
    jdict[ddict['name']] = {}
  name_jdict = jdict[ddict['name']]
  for key in ddict:
    if key == 'name':
      continue
    if key not in name_jdict:
      name_jdict[key] = []
    name_jdict[key].append(ddict[key])

res_list = []
for key, dict_value in jdict.items():
  temp_dict = {'name': key}
  for kitem, kvalue in dict_value.items():
    temp_dict[kitem] = set(kvalue)
  res_list.append(temp_dict)
print(res_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'name':'ABC', 'jid':['1','2'], 'eid': ['1']}, {'name':'CDE', 'jid':['1']}]
```

### EDIT

FYI: You could use a `defaultdict(list)` and reduce a couple of more lines further.

### EDIT2

Cast the final list to a set to avoid duplicates.

Comment: if there are more keys are present, then i am getting too many values to unpack

Comment: Please provide tangible examples

Comment: @Maws your question misses a lot of details

Comment: dlist = [{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'1','eid':'3'},{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'2'}, {'name':'CDE', 'jid':'1'}]

Comment: edited the sample dictionary an you check, also values has to be uniquq

Comment: then you just need to create dictionary of dictionary to append to the appropriate list. On a side note, you could also use pandas-dataframe and groupby for each column

Comment: @Maws I've edited the code and made it more generic to work for all cases

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
---> 16 for key, dict_value in jdict:

Comment: can you put one more condtion at set(jid) means to get the unique values not repating?

Answer (score 0):

you can use itertools to do this.

```
#import
from itertools import groupby 

#your list of dict
INFO=[{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'1'},{'name':'ABC', 'jid':'2'}, {'name':'CDE', 'jid':'1'}]


# define a fuction for key 
def key_func(k): 
    return k['name'] 
  
# sorting is need before grouping
INFO = sorted(INFO, key=key_func) 


out_list=[]

#grouping by name key 
for key, value in groupby(INFO, key_func): 
    print(key) 
    temp_dict={'name':key}
    for item in value:
        if 'jid' in  temp_dict.keys():
            temp_dict['jid'].append(item['jid'])
        else:
            temp_dict['jid']=[item['jid']]
    out_list.append(temp_dict)
print(out_list)
```